# How to set a C version for extern "C"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, extern

I have C++ code with some C code in it

```
extern "C"{
 ...
}
int main(){
...
}
```

I compile it with something like

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

What's the version of the `C` standard used to compile the `C` part of my code ? How can I explicitly set a version for my C snippets?

Answer (score 9):

Code in an `extern "C"` block is still compiled as C++ (C++11 in your case). `extern "C"` just gives it `C` linkage.

C linkage means that functions defined in the block can be called from C, and functions declared but not defined must be defined by a C program, or otherwise by an object file with C linkage.

If you want to write C code, write it in C, and use a C compiler. `extern "C"` is for writing C++ code that can be called from C, or for allowing C++ code to call C (or C ABI) code.

Comment: I already knew about the linkage part, I was expecting more flexibility while compiling.

Comment: @user2485710: Your expectation was wrong. If anything, you get less flexibility, since you can't have function signatures that are incompatible with C.

Comment: @user2485710 if you want to compile C code, use a C compiler and don't put it in a C++ file (because then it is not C code).

Comment: @user2485710: it doesn't make much sense to change the language semantics to C mid-file, several complications with the C++ stuff that has already been declared in the file would arise (e.g.: could you access global C++ objects declared above?), for essentially no gain... if you want to have some code compiled as C, put it in a `.c` file and tell to your build system to compile it as C, and link everything together at the end.

Comment: @crashmstr well all the compilers that I know are basically more than just a compiler for one single language, they are suites with support for multiple language at the same time, that's why I was expecting something different. Anyway, if this is it, I guess I will do things differently .

Comment: @MatteoItalia actually previous declarations are not a big problem with `extern` since they will automatically get the same linkage as dictated by the aforementioned declaration .

Comment: @user2485710: I'm saying something like `std::ofstream os; extern "C" { stuff };` Can *stuff* access `os`? Only with C-struct like semantic? What about calling functions? How should it deal with exceptions? All this stuff has to be specified in the standard, and it's simply not worth the effort.